# Crash in native libraries loaded twice by System.load

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

Here I have two activities: `HomeActivity`(the launcher activity) and `MainActivity`(load
native library and call native methods):

```java
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'reproducecrash' library on application startup.

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeDynamicallyLoadedCode")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        //copy .so to app file directory
        File libSavePath = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/libreproducecrash.so");
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("libreproducecrash.so");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(libSavePath);
            byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
            int byteCount=0;
            while((byteCount=is.read(buffer))!=-1) {
                fos.write(buffer,0,byteCount);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            is.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.load(libSavePath.getPath());
        Log.i("MyLogger", libSavePath.getPath() + " loaded");

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = binding.sampleText;
        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'reproducecrash' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

I redirect the library compilation output path to `app/src/main/assets`. And copy it to app file directory on runtime(simulate downloading a library from remote server). Loading the native library to VM by calling `System.load` and make any jni calls. Everything works fine, **while the app crash when I exit `MainActivity` then enter it again, Even the first logging message in native method is not emitted**:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_reproducecrash_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyLogger", "Logging in JNI");
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

I have uploaded the minimal reproducible codes to github, please check it [here](https://github.com/FinleyPan/reproduceAndrdoidJNICrash) , Thanks!

**Update**
the logcat reports:

```
2022-12-12 20:10:32.446 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash I/MyLogger: /data/user/0/com.example.reproducecrash/files/libreproducecrash.so loaded
2022-12-12 20:10:32.446 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash I/MyLogger: Logging in JNI
2022-12-12 20:10:32.496 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash I/Quality: Skipped: false 1 cost 25.242748
2022-12-12 20:10:32.919 21013-21035/com.example.reproducecrash E/BLASTBufferQueue: BLASTBufferItemConsumer::onDisconnect()
2022-12-12 20:10:36.294 21013-21035/com.example.reproducecrash E/BLASTBufferQueue: BLASTBufferItemConsumer::onDisconnect()
2022-12-12 20:10:43.026 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash I/oplus.android.OplusFrameworkFactoryImpl: get feature:IOplusDynamicVsyncFeature
2022-12-12 20:10:43.026 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash I/oplus.android.OplusFrameworkFactoryImpl: get feature:IOplusDynamicVsyncFeature
2022-12-12 20:10:43.026 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash I/oplus.android.OplusFrameworkFactoryImpl: get feature:IOplusDynamicVsyncFeature
2022-12-12 20:10:43.047 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash I/MyLogger: /data/user/0/com.example.reproducecrash/files/libreproducecrash.so loaded
2022-12-12 20:10:43.047 21013-21013/com.example.reproducecrash A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xe010 in tid 21013 (.reproducecrash), pid 21013 (.reproducecrash)
```

**Update**
a static boolean added to avoid loading library twice but still crashed:

```java
private static boolean sLibLoaded = false;

if(!sLibLoaded) {
    System.load(libSavePath.getPath());
    Log.i("MyLogger", libSavePath.getPath() + " loaded"); 
    sLibLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: When you say the app crashes, what does logcat report?

Comment: @Botje Hey, I have updated logcat reporting

Comment: Is it possible you are calling `System.load` on the same library twice in one process?

Comment: Did you try putting all of the library-loading code (including the file copying) inside the `if`, rather than just the `System.load` call?

Comment: @Michael Awesome! it fix crash

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael said, ensure the library **copy** and **load** once.